# Format number as percent and preserve CSS color based on number value

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, percentage, angularjs-filter

I'm using ng-grid to create a data table and apply color to cells based on their numerical value.  I also need to display those numbers as percentages.  I've been able to apply a filter to output the numbers as percents, but doing so wipes out the coloring based on numerical value.  How can I get both to work together?

http://plnkr.co/edit/S2oYiwZex7dNw1AQAB9j?p=preview`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
    space: "S",
    week1: 0,
    week2: 9,
    week3: 1
  }, {
    space: "E",
    week1: 0,
    week2: 0,
    week3: 0
  }, {
    space: "B",
    week1: 4,
    week2: 11,
    week3: 16
  }, {
    space: "C",
    week1: 0,
    week2: 0,
    week3: 0
  }, {
    space: "S",
    week1: 0,
    week2: 0,
    week3: 0
  }];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'space',
        displayName: ''
      }, {
        field: 'week1',
        displayName: '12/30',
        cellTemplate: '<div ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field) | percentage:100"><div ng-class="{first: row.getProperty(col.field) <= 5}"><div ng-class="{second: row.getProperty(col.field) >= 5}"><div ng-class="{third: row.getProperty(col.field) >= 10}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div></div></div></div>'
      }, {
        field: 'week2',
        displayName: '1/6',
        cellTemplate: '<div ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field) | percentage:100"><div ng-class="{first: row.getProperty(col.field) <= 5}"><div ng-class="{second: row.getProperty(col.field) >= 5}"><div ng-class="{third: row.getProperty(col.field) >= 10}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div></div></div>'
      }, {
        field: 'week3',
        displayName: '1/13',
        cellTemplate: '<div ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field) | percentage:100"><div ng-class="{first: row.getProperty(col.field) <= 5}"><div ng-class="{second: row.getProperty(col.field) >= 5}"><div ng-class="{third: row.getProperty(col.field) >= 10}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div></div></div>'
      },

    ]
  };
});

app.filter('percentage', function() {
  return function(input, max) {
    if (isNaN(input)) {
      return input;
    }
    return Math.floor((input * 100) / max) + '%';
  };
});
```

```css
/*style.css*/

.gridStyle {
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px
}
.first {
  background-color: #fff9f8;
  color: black;
}
.second {
  background-color: #ffeeeb;
  color: black;
}
.third {
  background-color: #ffded8;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the filter on the cellText, what you want is to format the output of the col field and print it as a percentage

`<div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field) | percentage:100}}</div>`

cf: http://plnkr.co/edit/wiKRgGK8QtNyTyrjpgg8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, filters create 2-way binding, and in case you do not need that, you can define a cell template as such:

```
let percentageCellTemplate = '<div class="ngCellText">{{grid.appScope.Math.round(row.entity[col.field])}}%</div>'
```

and then use it:

```
columnDefs : [
    { field : 'continuedRate', displayName : 'continuedRate (%)', type: 'number', cellTemplate: percentageCellTemplate}
]
```

Note: we wrap ui-grid with our code and set Math on our scope, so ui-grid lets us get our own scope by accessing `grid.appScope`